# How do I determine my limits of integration for a density function?

Tags: probability

Let's suppose I have X and Y as being random variables that have a joint density f(x,y) = [something], with a <= x <= b and c <= x <= d as my domain.

If I wanted to find P(X > Y), I would need to integrate the above density function with appropriate limits of integration. However, I am not sure how to go about finding the region where X > Y is true. How can I determine this algebraically given the information that I have?

For example...

(Note: I am NOT looking for a specific answer to THIS question but you can motivate/show the above using this if you like).

Let X and Y have a joint density of $f(x,y) = \frac{6}{7}(x+y)^2$, $0 \leq x \leq 1$ and $0 \leq y \leq 1$.

Find $P(X > Y)$. Find $P(X + Y \leq 1)$. Find $P(X \leq 1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example,if $x\in[0,1]$ and $y\in[0,1]$, $$\Pr(X>Y)=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{x}f_{X,Y}(x,y)dydx$$
this is because we divide the $1\times1$ ($xy$) square by the line $y=x$. Below the line we have $x>y$.

Comment: Great explanation!

Comment: Hmm, I am still stuck with P(X + Y <= 1). Any ideas how I could work this out? I'm not sure what kind of lie to draw.

Comment: consider the line $y=-x+1$.

Comment: How did you figure that out? :o

Comment: If you still haven't figured it out, you just need to assume equality and solve for $y$. Equality holds on the line and one side of the equation is greater on either side of the line.

Comment: Ah! Yes. That makes more sense... great explanation again thanks.